# Different Log Level for Different Camel Routes

Tags: logging, apache-camel

I have 5 different camel routes; by default, they have INFO log level set; when I crisis time we want to set to DEBUG log level only for one particular camel route; is it possible? Please note that currently I have a logger based on camel route id.

EDIT:
Added logger settings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more how you configured those loggers to be INFO

Comment: @ClausIbsen, Please check my edits.

Comment: You can use log:set command in karaf to change logging level. See the karaf documentation

Comment: My problem is that if I do "log:set DEBUG sift", log level for all the came routes will be affected. Is there a way to set it only for a particular route?

Comment: No that is not possible. You can use the log eip and use different logger name so you can configure them individually. http://camel.apache.org/logeip.html